# Meaning of the notation

Tags: notation, calculus

It should be a very simple question but I can find nowhere being precise on this: what is the meaning of the notation
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla f(x)|dx
\end{equation}
(not mentioning the $\int|Df(x)|dx$ notation).

Is it the same as
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}f(x)\right|dx
$$
I met this when I tried to read some books on total variation, but obviously the authors assumed readers already knew this convention.

Comment: Can this help? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $|\nabla f(x)|$ will be "the" norm, one could say the length, of the vector $\nabla f(x) = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}f(x), \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}f(x) ) $.

The most common way to define "the" norm of a vector is the Euclidean norm,
that is, $|(y_1, \dots, y_n)| = \sqrt{y_1^2+\dots +y_n^2}$, which corresponds to our usual geometric idea of length,  in your case would mean
$$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f(x))^2}$$
There are however other ways to define the norm of a vector, for example what you wrote would be commonly referred to as the $1$-norm of the vector.

If there is no further commentary, it ought to be what I said initially.